# Using Spring to get all data asynchronously inserted into a database

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a Spring REST controller with a `POST` and `GET` method written in Kotlin. Both exist on a front end application. When someone clicks an upload button it triggers the `POST` request and the return value of that dictates whether or not the `GET` request gets triggered.

The `POST` takes a multifile object and returns a reference ID to the files. Before returning the ID it takes each file, saves it to disk, then adds the file's location to a message queue for further processing which includes moving the files to a different (permanent) location and adding that location to a database.

The GET request is triggered when the ID response comes back to get the location of those files to display any images that may need to be displayed.

Since the files are being added to the database asynchronously I can't know when all file locations are going to be available. What I've done for this is code in an exponential back off in the GET request to query the database for the files and if the number of files returned doesn't match the number of files expected I add time to a `sleep` variable and put the thread to sleep for that amount of time. Once the thread wakes up, it repeats this process until all files are found or the `sleep` variable crosses a predefined threshold.

I'm sure there is a much better way of a approaching this problem, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: I am a bit confused about this GET request. How triggers this GET request? A front-end application? Another microservice? Can you please clarify this? Thanks!

Comment: Added some clarification in the post. A user on the front-end will trigger the `POST` request and based on the return value of the `POST` the front-end application will send a `GET` request.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to establish a WebSocket communication between Frontend and Backend that is kept open until all the files are properly stored and their location can be sent back to the Frontend. However, I have some doubts if this isn't overkill for your use case.

Another possibility is, instead of having the thread checking from time and actually hanging the Frontend call, simply answer that the processing of the files hasn't finished yet and let the Frontend handle this case and try again later instead of pushing this logic into the Backend.